# Which roles must have an impersonated user to parse IIS applications?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-8, user-roles

When executing the following c# code impersonating a user I have an exception (I do not have details on the exception):

```
  public static void CheckIIS()
  {
    // list al websites on IIS
    DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC");
    foreach (DirectoryEntry ws in w3svc.Children)
    {
      if (ws.SchemaClassName != "IIsWebServer")
        continue;
      //
      // Website found!
    }
  }
```

Which roles the windows user must have to avoid exceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You should use `Microsoft.Web.Administration` to consume IIS API (this has been the rule of thumb for more than one decade, and legacy APIs can break anytime). 2. Impersonation is not supported in all cases when consuming Windows APIs. 3. IIS API was usually designed to be consumed by local administrators only, so the process must run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your exception is "Access denied". This is a common issue when using impersonation authentication.
You can try set this impersonation user being a member of IIS_IUSRS group. It solves the similar problem.
[image]